# Is reading from a int[] array while another thread updates that int[] array safe?

Tags: c#

Two threads. 
The first furiously reading elements from the array.
The second is equally furious in updating elements by reading them and incrementing them by an arbitrary amount.

Is this safe? can anything go wrong in this situation? I don't mind that the reading thread reads an 'old' value while the updating thread is still in the process of updating. I just want to make sure the reader doesn't ever read a number that was not written and also that an exception cannot occur.

Comment: I've updated to explain what I don't want to happen

Comment: There will be no exception. There wouldn't even be an exception if "half-written" updates could happen, which they can't.

Comment: Do you have any requirement that a *third* thread that is also reading the array sees a consistent ordering of the operations of the other two threads? Because that is not guaranteed by the C# memory model without introducing barriers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `int` update is atomic on all cpu architectures that can execute managed code.  In other words, you won't read a value that has just a single byte modified by the writing thread.  Value type values larger than 32-bit, like `long` and `double` are not guaranteed atomic.  Object references are also always atomic.

Comment: `long` must be atomic on x86-64, and also memory pointers are atomic

Comment: @SargeBorsch: To be picky: the C# *language* guarantees that pointers and references are atomic on all architectures when aligned. Though the runtime or the hardware might make a guarantee for longs, the C# language does not.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't thread-safe - you aren't guaranteed that one thread gets the proper data.

Comment: But can you be guaranteed that the reading thread will read either new or old data, rather than some other irrelevant data?

Comment: It doesn't appear that he's concerned about stale reads, only about potential run time exceptions, making me fear for the place this implementation is occuring.

Comment: don't worry preston, it's just some autopilot code I am writing for the aircraft that flies around our nuclear power plant

Comment: If that's all, I suggest doing away with the array at all and returning Rand.Next() on every call.